# Will existing Kubuntu 14.04 work after UEFI motherboard upgrade?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, uefi

I've been using Kubuntu 14.04 since a few weeks after it dropped, but it's getting time to upgrade my desktop computer; the Core2Quad with 8 GB RAM isn't really up to some software I want to run well, so a Core i5 or Pentium G6450 seems like what I need (and can afford) to improve my single-core thread performance.

Problem is, I doubt I can find an LGA1151 motherboard that won't have UEFI.  Other than MB, CPU, and RAM, I expect to keep all my existing hardware (which runs fine with both 14.04 LTS and my reserve 16.04 LTS installation) -- GTX950 1GB video, PCI SCSI card, and PCIEx1 multi-io, plus two platter hard disks, CD-RW and the SSD that has the OS and /home on it.

I don't foresee hardware compatibility problems with the new motherboard, but I don't want to have to install everything clean.  Can I have reasonable confidence that a (lower end, say around $100) LGA1151 motherboard will allow my Kubuntu to run, or will the (seemingly unavoidable) UEFI cause trouble?  Or, alternately, how can I check (with the limited specs found on shopping sites) whether a motherboard has UEFI or BIOS?

Comment: Most UEFI systems have CSM. CSM - UEFI Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which emulates a BIOS mode. My Asus motherboard actually was difficult to get to boot in UEFI mode. It had settings for UEFI  & CSM/BIOS/Legacy, but only if I turned on UEFI only would it boot in UEFI mode. You will need to make sure UEFI Secure Boot is OFF as BIOS is not Secure boot. And may have to make a few other settings. There are some advantages to UEFI, but perhaps more with using gpt. I used gpt with my old BIOS system back in 2011. I did have trouble trying to use an old power supply with new motherboard.

Comment: You can always switch the MB to CSM mode. And also switching to UEFI mode does not require a reinstall. You can create a EFI partition and reinstall only grub.

Comment: @oldfred Fortunately, my PSU is new(ish) -- it was replaced with a gaming supply when my last motherboard failed, to eliminate PSU as a cause of the replacement not booting.  IIRC, I've got 600 watts installed last fall.

Comment: My 2006 build with new motherboard in 2009 was Core2 Duo. I was itching to get new UEFI system, but decided to install small SSD as boot drive in 2011, expecting to use it in new UEFI system shortly. Old system booted so quick & worked so well I could not justify (to self) much less my wife. So it was 2014 before new UEFI system. Do you have SSD?

Comment: OS is on SSD, alongside two older platter drives (one is IDE, but I can stand to remove that one if there's no IDE connector on the new MB).

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of possible ways to transfer an old BIOS-mode installation to a new UEFI-based motherboard or computer and have it boot. These include:

- **Use the CSM** -- As oldfred writes in his comment, the Compatibility Support Module (CSM) exists to enable older BIOS-based OSes to boot on a new computer. Most new UEFI-based PCs include a CSM, the main exceptions being 32-bit UEFIs used in some tablets and convertible PCs. Using the CSM usually requires modifying at least one firmware setting, but details vary greatly from one computer to another. Note, however, that using the CSM actually complicates the boot path, as described in detail on [this page of mine.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) I therefore ordinarily advise against its use; however, in your specific case the CSM is likely to be the simplest approach, at least in the short term.
- **Convert to an EFI-mode boot** -- The vast majority of an Ubuntu installation is firmware-agnostic. The main difference is in the boot loader, and you can install an EFI-mode boot loader on a system that was originally installed in BIOS mode. Doing so will, however, require creating an [EFI System Partition (ESP),](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition) which is a smallish (~200-1000MiB) FAT partition that holds the EFI boot loader. EFI-mode booting is also generally done from a [GUID Partition Table (GPT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) disk, although this is not strictly necessary. (Some EFIs are finicky and may require use of a GPT disk, but this is rare.) Thus, you may need to resize a partition to make room for the ESP, and converting from MBR to GPT (which my `gdisk` tool, included standard with Ubuntu, can do) is advisable, too. You can use [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to install an EFI-mode version of GRUB, but you'd need to boot from an emergency disk to do this. Alternatively, you could use my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) on a USB drive or CD-R to boot Ubuntu in EFI mode and install the EFI-mode GRUB, rEFInd, or something else from that boot.
- **Re-install or upgrade** -- You've already thought of this, obviously. I'm not positive, but I suspect that upgrading to 16.04, using an EFI-mode boot of the 16.04 installer, should install the EFI-mode version of GRUB while preserving your personal files and most system settings. You'd have to prepare the hard disk first, though, with an ESP and possibly a conversion from MBR to GPT. This approach might be worth considering, given that we're more than half way through 14.04's support lifetime.
- **Back up and re-install** -- As a more extreme version of the preceding, you could back up your personal files (in `/home` or wherever), do a 100% fresh installation, and then restore your personal files. This might be worth considering if you're running into issues like poorly-sized partitions or multiple sub-optimal software configurations you want to correct.

Also, note that new hardware might not be properly supported by old software. The 14.04.5 version of Ubuntu uses the 4.4 kernel series, which is starting to get a bit old. (That said, Canonical does provide updates over the "stock" Linux kernel, so it may be significantly better in hardware support than its version number alone would suggest.) If you're planning to get a new motherboard, I strongly recommend you research hardware compatibility with the version of Ubuntu you plan to use, especially if it's anything but the latest version. You may be forced to upgrade to 16.04 to make proper use of your hardware. This is true even without the firmware issues you're considering.

Comment: I haven't switched to 16.04 to date because, frankly, KDE5 is ugly and the tools didn't exist last time I cared to check to make it look like the KDE4 customizations I've been using for five years.  However, it looks like the motherboard upgrade is temporarily off the table, so this is moot for a while.